# Lelong number of curvature of Kawamata's hermitian metric

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, lelong-number

> Let $X,Y$ are two projective varieties and $f:X\to Y$ is an Iitaka
>   fibration. Consider the following singular hermitian metric
>   $$h(\sigma,\sigma)=\left(\int_{X_y}|\sigma|^{\frac{2}{m!}}\right)^{m!}$$
>   where $y\in Y$ and $\sigma$ is a section of $$\frac{1}{m!}f_*\mathcal
>  O_X(m!K_{X/Y})|_{X_y}$$
>
> then, the curvature of hermitian metric $h$, i.e.,
>   $\sqrt{-1}\Theta_h$  has zero [Lelong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lelong_number)?
>   In other words, ***the Weil-Petersson current on moduli space of Calabi-Yau varieties has zero Lelong number?***

Note that direct image of relative line bundle is nef

and if the line bundle $L\to X$ be a nef and big then there exists a hermitian metric on $L$ with vanishing Lelong number. But this question is specific

Lelong number gives a lot of information to us. For example,
Let $X$
be a projective manifold and
$(L, h)$
a positive
,
singular hermitian line bundle
,
whose Lelong numbers vanish everywhere. Then
$L$
is
nef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By theorem 2 and Poroposition 6, of the paper, Georg Schumacher and Hajime Tsuji, Quasi-projectivity of moduli spaces of polarized varieties, Annals of Mathematics,159(2004), 597–639

the Weil-Petersson metric has zero Lelong number.

http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v159-n2-p03.pdf

So, this tells us that the direct image of relative line bundle is nef

Or Theorem 3.4 http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~schumac/doubar.pdf